# Save a picture inside of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
- Save a picture from my computer's harddrive to the WPF's application.
- After adding a picture, you are enable to view the picture in visual Studio after updating the solution and projects.

Problem:

> I don't know HOW to save a picture inside of my WPF's application. To
>   be more specificed I want the picture to be saved in the map
>   ArticlePicture from project DataAccessLibrary.

Again, I know how to do it in ASP.net MVC but not in WPF application. The syntax from MVC doesn't work in WPF application.

Please remember that the picture is not directly from the Internet. I upload the picture directly from my personal computer to the WPF application. The WPF application is stored in my personal PC.

The input data of the picture take place in the project MediaStore

The directory address of the picture is:
"C:\Users\Fullmetalboy\Desktop\Firefox download\picture.gif"

Directory address of the project and its map ArticlePicture is:
"E:\Project\MediaStore\DataAccessLibrary\ArticlePicture\"

The goal is to add and copy the picture to the map "ArticlePicture" with this new address
"E:\Project\MediaStore\DataAccessLibrary\ArticlePicture\picture.gif

I have tried these links but unfortunately, it didn't provide me any success.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx#_imageformats

### [image]

Syntax code in WPF application

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|gif files (*.gif)|*.gif|jpeg files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";

    dlg.Multiselect = false;
    bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        Stream fInfo = dlg.OpenFile();



        using (System.Drawing.Image correctPicture = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fInfo))
        {

            if (correctPicture.Width <= 180 && correctPicture.Height <= 250)
            {
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName);

                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/"), fileName);

            }
            else
            {

            }                    




        }


    }


}
```

---

Syntax code in ASP.net mVC        //

```
// POST: /Admin/Produkt_ListaCreate/

[HttpPost, Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Produkt_ListaCreate(Bok pMyBok, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    if (file != null)
    {

        using (System.Drawing.Image correctPicture = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
        {
            if (correctPicture.Width <= 180 && correctPicture.Height <= 250)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                pMyBok.BokBildUrl = "/Content/Images/" + fileName;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["message"] = "Den uppladdade bilden fungerar inte pga att den uppfyller inte storlekens och formatets kriterier.";

                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }
        }   


    } // if (file != null)

    _myIBookRepository.Add(pMyBok);
    _myIBookRepository.Spara();
    TempData["message"] = "En boken är skapad.";

    return View("index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.MapPath is not going to work in a WPF application - its for IIS applications.

Where does this WPF application run? If its running from the same machine, what directory is it being run from? You need some way for the WPF application to determine where the ArticlePicture directory resides.

Assuming you are running the WPF application from the web server, you know where the directory resides, and the WPF application has permissions to access the directory, then all you need to do is to a file copy operation. (I see no reason to save the file back out of the WPF application if it is not modified).

I suspect maybe your intention is to upload the picture to the website via the WPF application. If so you might need to explain more clearly.

Comment: "Where does this WPF application run?" it is running on my PC. 
"what directory is it being run from?"  It's a long address and it is no problem for my to retrieve the located address of the picture and the WPF application.

"I suspect maybe your intention is to upload the picture to the website via the WPF application. If so you might need to explain more clearly." nonononono... The wpf application and pictures are inside of my PC and i want to uppload the picture to my WPF application. I other words, I wannt the picture to be inside of my WPF application.

Comment: Im confused by "inside my WPF application". Do you mean you want to view the picture?

Comment: "inside my WPF application", The goal is to save and copy a picture that shall be in the map ArticlePicture (from project DataAccessLibrary.).. Please tell if you need more information?

Comment: Copy the picture from where to where?

Comment: The directory address of the picture is:
"C:\Users\Fullmetalboy\Desktop\Firefox download\picture.gif"

Directory address of the project and its map ArticlePicture is:

"E:\Project\MediaStore\DataAccessLibrary\ArticlePicture\"

The goal is to add and copy the picture to the map "ArticlePicture" with this new address
"E:\Project\MediaStore\DataAccessLibrary\ArticlePicture\picture.gif

Comment: It works perfectly!!! One disadvantage is that you cannot view the picture in VS2010, If possible after adding the picture in the map "ArticlePicture", the Visual Studio would view the picture. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: To see the added file in the VS Project Explorer window you need to "add existing item". Alternatively click "show all files", then you can just use the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, that directory does not exist at runtime as it's compiled into an assembly. You will have to use a folder that exists on disk in which you have sufficient rights to actually right the image data.

I would say you make a folder outside the root of you webapplication in which you can write the pictures. You want this to be outside the root of your web application as you don't want to have your pictures served directly if someone knows the URL I guess.

Comment: All pictures and WPF application is stored only in my PC and not on the Internet.